# What is the Freudenthal compactification of a wildly punctured n-sphere?

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, riemannian-geometry, manifolds, compactifications

Let $C$ be a compact and totally-disconnected subspace of the $n$-sphere $\mathbb{S}^n$, where $n\geq 2$.

**Question:** Must the Freudenthal compactification of $\mathbb{S}^n \setminus C$ be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^n$?

The case where $C$ is homeomorphic to the Cantor set is interesting.

For $n=2$ the answer is yes, see e.g. Corollary 1.5. in [Georgakopoulos - On planar Cayley graphs and Kleinian groups](https://doi.org/10.1090/tran/8026).
For $n=3$ I suspect it is still easy using a triangulation of $\mathbb{S}^n \setminus C$.

Comment: The terminology is so evocative!

Comment: The space of ends will be homeomorphic to $C$, and the end compactification will be homeomorphic to $S^n$. Since it’s disconnected, we can find a finite open cover by at least two disjoint connected open sets. Then one checks that these give neighborhoods of the ends (puncturing by the Cantor set can’t disconnect them). Now repeat with the Cantor sets inside each of these open sets.

Comment: @IanAgol: I'm not convinced. To find a neighborhood of an end $\omega$, we need to display a *compact* subset $K$ of $\mathbb{S}^n \setminus C$ that separates $\omega$ from some other end, don't we? How do you find such $K$? It is important that $K$ be disjoint from $C$.

Comment: @IanAgol: ... I got convinced, ignore the previous comment.

Comment: If $S^n-C$ is the boundary of a noncompact manifold, i.e., a $(n+1)$-ball $B^{n+1}$ minus $C$, then we can use the manifold completion theorem (https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S1793525319500754) to compactify $B^{n+1}-C$, which is essentially the end compactification. Then one restricts the neighborhoods of infinity in $B^{n+1}-C$ to the corresponding boundaries to obtain the neighborhoods of infinity in $S^n-C$.

Comment: The right question is whether the embedding $S^n-C\to C$ is the Freudenthal compactification (not just whether there is an arbitrary homeomorphism) and the answer is yes too. In addition it holds in an arbitrary compact connected topological manifold of dimension $\ge 2$, boundary allowed (and probably anything connected and locally homeomorphic to simplicial complexes with no isolated vertex/edge).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. The key ingredient is that given any $x,y\in C$, we can find a compact connected $K\subset \mathbb{S}^n$ separating $x$ from $y$. To see this, notice that as $C$ is totally-disconnected, we can decompose $C$ into disjoint open sets $C_x \ni x, C_y \ni y$. Let $\epsilon:= d(C_x, C_y)$, and cover $C$ by (finitely many) balls of radius $\epsilon/3$. Then we can take the complement of this cover to be the desired set $K$.